# I can't disable the firewall from my router

Tags: port-forwarding, nat

I have the router D-link DSL 2500-E, the simulator is here http://suporte.dlink.com.br/suporte/emuladores/ADSL/dsl-2500E/emulador/fw-dmz.htm.

I want to open and use the incoming ports: 443 (https), 1243 (mssql), 3306 (mysql), but I can't really open these ports from my router, I tried almost everything :(

- ACL/Access Control List (This can open the ports for the services: web, telnet, ftp, tftp, snmp, ping)
- DMZ (this can open the ports for HTTP, FTP, SMTP but not 443, 1243, 3306)
- Virtual Server (supposedly I can open all the ports that I want, but when I scan my public IP with `nmap` the ports are filtered :/ , I guess for the firewall and I don't find the point of this option if the firewall can't be disabled)
- Googling a while I found that possibly the router can't do "reverse NAT" but I am not completely sure of that.
- Before buying a new router my last options are:

  - Tunnel ssh? (but as I can't open the ssh port, it is useless too)
  - VPN? (I don't know how to make it work)
  - Update or modify the router firmware (Is it possible?)

I really need your help guys :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you write "DMZ (this can open the ports for HTTP, FTP, SMTP but not 443, 1243, 3306)" <-- where on earth did you read that?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the port triggering section: http://suporte.dlink.com.br/suporte/emuladores/ADSL/dsl-2500E/emulador/nat_portrigger.htm

From there you would specify the port and the address that you would like that port to be forwarded to. This will effectively "open" the port and allow traffic to the IP of the desired machine.

The router is acting as a NAT which is 'translating' addresses from the outside (WAN) to your internal network (LAN).

Comment: Atari911 thanks so much for the advice, i must that i didn't try it this option  for the title "Entries in this table are used to restrict certain types of data packets from your local network to Internet through the Gateway" , i just try  and the ports keeping closed :( according to http://www.mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx, mi local ip is static, mi windows firewall completely open for out and in, and netstat -ano the service is listening in 10.0.0.6:3306 that is mi local ip, thanks again for the try :).

Comment: -1 you have not even used the word "firewall" which is even in his title, so you haven't clearly addressed his question. Perhaps you are meaning to say that what he is seeing is not his firewall, then you should say that. Perhaps you want to say that his firewall is disabled, then you should say that. Perhaps you want to say that you don't know if his firewall is disabled or not, then you should say that.